# how to connect to google play service and load leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I want to connect my game with google play service. i have read documentation on android developer and try to following type-a-number sample and still can't load leaderboard.

i have import baseGameUtils, but i use andengine so i didn't use extends BaseGameActivity from google.

what i have until now:
- GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) return success
- startActivityForResult(pickAccountIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT); is working well and i got my account name from onActivityResult(..);
-  i already put this on my manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

**my questions are**
1. can i use google play service without extends BaseGameActivity?
2. if i use gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(); after i got my account name, i got this on log cat. (what this connected mean? because i still got error on next question)

```
08-25 00:09:01.890: D/BaseGameActivity(11222): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0  
08-25 00:09:01.890: D/BaseGameActivity(11222): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.  
08-25 00:09:01.890: D/BaseGameActivity(11222): All clients now connected. Sign-in successful.  
08-25 00:09:01.890: D/BaseGameActivity(11222): All requested clients connected. Sign-in succeeded!
```

3 . how do i use connect()? i have read and tried about gameClient and GameClientBuilder but i have no idea how to use that. when i tried run this code.

```
startActivityForResult(gameHelper.getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(), RC_UNUSED);
```

i got this log.

```
08-25 00:09:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11222): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

4 . to use leaderboard i know i must use code from google play store such as CgkIx********AIQAA. but i didn't found where i must put this code to load leaderboard.

sorry for long question, but i think if there is a sample that only for connect and either access achievement or leaderboard it will answer all my question. please don't tell me to see type-a-number sample, i did that and i need another sample code.

**update, my snipped code**

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GameHelperListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
  gameHelper = new GameHelper(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v.equals(loadData)) {
    if(gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
      gameHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES, Scopes.GAMES);
      startActivityForResult(gameHelper.getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(), RC_UNUSED);
    }
  }
  else if(v.equals(loginButton)) {
    Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,null,new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE},true,null,null,null,null) ;
    startActivityForResult(googlePicker, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      finish();
    }
    return;
  }
  else if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
      gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "This application requires a Google account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      finish();
    }
    return;
  }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

// this 2 methods not called, is this also because my code is wrong?
@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
  Log.d("rush", "on sign in failed");
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
  Log.d("rush", "on sign in succeed");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. Take a look at the `BaseGameActivity` source and see that it largely just wraps `GameHelper`. You can implement the calls to `GameHelper` yourself - in fact, you can probably copy some code directly from `BaseGameActivity`. I'm a bit confused, because it appears that your code is already using `GameHelper`. It looks like you are mixing `GameHelper` calls with `BaseGameActivity` calls. You cannot do this, and it will result in... errors like you are getting.
2. The LogCat you see means that all of your clients are connected. The default call to `GameHelper.setup()` just requests the Games client. If you aren't using `BaseGameActivity` and want different clients, do:

   ```
   gameHelper = new GameHelper(this);
   gameHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES | GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS);
   ```
3. `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` is an asynchronous method with a callback when it finishes. Are you running it that way? `GameHelper.GameHelperListener` is the interface to implement. If you are using gameHelper, make sure to register the callback. See the `this` in the setup call above? That's registering the callback (`this` is my main activity).

   As I said above, it looks like you are mixing `GameHelper` calls with `BaseGameActivity` calls. The `GameHelper` that is connected is the `BaseGameActivity.mHelper` instance, not any `GameHelper` you might have instantiated. Make sure that if you are using `BaseGameActivity` that you are not using `GameHelper` as well.
4. If you want to display a single leaderboard, use the `GamesClient.getLeaderboardIntent(string, int)` or method to get the `Intent`. The string is the code you have (CgkIx****AIQAA).

   ```
   startActivityForResult(gameHelper.getGamesClient().getLeaderboardIntent(
           leaderboard_id, RC_UNUSED);
   ```

   Again, make sure you are using the correct `getGamesClient()` method, depending on if you are using `BaseGameActivity` or `GameHelper` directly.

Comment: i have update my question with my code.  
1. i'm not extend BaseGameActivity. so its mean i can directly use GameHelper with code similiar with BaseGameActivity?

2. what is client stand for? is that for multiplayer?  
  
3. i also thought about setup. i put this before beginUserInitiatedSignin().. gameHelper.setup(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES, Scopes.GAMES);
and nothing happen.  
  
4. i have try all i can do. but still can't find how to using GamesClient() correcly.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Client, in this case, is the API client. You want to use the Google Play Games Services client for achievements and leaderboards. Multiplayer requires the Plus client as well. 3. If you are only using the Games client, just call `gameHelper.setup()` immediately after `gameHelper = new GameHelper(this);`. Your call to setup is very broken - you can only pass it the integer flags Client_NONE, Client_GAMES, Client_PLUS, CLient_APPSTATE, or Client_ALL (or some combination of the first 4 OR'd together).

Comment: i have notice what you mean that i mixing gameHelper with baseGameActivity. currently i already put code as you said. but stil it not called the listener. for now, when i run BeginUserInitiatedSignIn() is going well, but after choose my id, my gameHelper.isSignedIn() is still false. and ofcourse. any advice??

Comment: It's likely that you are having issues now with keys. Have you pulbished your Google Play Game Services settings in the Play console? Are you sure that the key you are signing your APK with matches the key that you used to create the GPGS item? Search around on stackoverflow, you'll find plenty of discussion of GPGS sign in failures. Personally, sometimes even if everything is set up right, my debug APKs may or may not sign in properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic information how to use GameHelper without BaseGameActivity:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity