# How to implement leaderboard in Android application?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement leaderboard in my Android application, but I don't know to connect to Google Play Game Services and display/update leaderboard.

I read all Google documentation, searched on internet, but I couldn't find solution.

I created everything except code. I created game in Developer Console, added Leaderboard, downloaded Google Play Services to Android Studio, 
updated AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Can someone please post all code that needs to go inside

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
}
```

, required to connect to Google Play Game Services and display/update leaderboard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421635